# What is the best way to have a div overlap multiple table cells

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, calendar, html-table

I am building a calendar web page using jQuery and asp.net-mvc [similar to this](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/selectable.html) and I can't figure out how this example is supporting events that span multiple days  (it shows the event as a single item across multiple days in the view).

Using firebug, I see that the calendar is simply a table:

[image]

but I can't figure out how they have the event  div that crosses multiple cells of a table like the "Long Event" in the image below?

[image]

Comment: No one has mentioned that the example table doesn't span for the layout. It is "faked" with a blank area for the events which started on a prior day (this makes "all day event" on the 1st the 2nd item). Then completely outside/separate from the table is a `position:absolute` div for the "Long Event" content text along with styling and link handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the answers above:

```
<TD style="position: relative">
  <DIV style="position: absolute; z-index: ?; width: ?px;... ">
  </DIV>
</TD>
```

you may need to provide a z-index to ensure that your element appears on top of other table cell contents..

Comment: multiple events will appear on top of each other instead of spacing down below one another (for instance, thursday has the long event and all day event) with position: absolute, they'll just stack on top of each other

Comment: of course. the downside of absolute positioning is you have to specify top explicitly.  

Yet another option is "faking" the span of multiple cells, by putting multiple DIVs in each TD that are styled with CSS to look like a single event.

Answer (score 1):

Put the DIV in the calendar cell (`position:relative`) and use absolute positioning. This takes it out of the layout and it is no longer restricted by its container.

Comment: the events will stack on top of each other... this works fine for one event each day but if events overlap they're going to stack... solves one problem creates another.

Comment: Yes, each additional one needs to have a different y-position. You can calculate this when you place them. Alternately use a wrapper an UL/LI - make the item LI and position the wrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative;` = flow layout, things will take up space and push elements around

`position: absolute;` = absolute layout, things will no longer take up space or push other elements around, they will be positioned by their top/left values relative to their parent*

The way they created the calendar, everything is relative, except for the events themselves.  They set those divs to use absolute positioning, so they are effectively floating outside of the regular flow.  This way, they can grow into other cells w/o disturbing the layout.

*Keep in mind that objects default to relative positioning, but when you explicitly set an object to relative positioning, you reset the top/left coordinates any child using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the " overlap" effect with some css.

HTML for a table cell (a day of your calendar)

```
<td>
  <div>
    <div class="a occupied"> occupied [AV]  [1]  </div>
    <div class="spacer occupied "> </div>
    <div class="b occupied"> occupied [AV]  [1]</div>
  </div>
</td>
```

CSS for inner divs

```
 table.vertical-table tr > td > div > .checkin,
 table.vertical-table tr > td > div > .checkout, 
 table.vertical-table tr > td > div > .occupied {
    background: #139ff7;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

CSS for a specific events ending(top) or beginning(bottom) in the during daytime

```
table.vertical-table tr > td > div > div.a,
table.vertical-table tr > td > div > div.b {
  height: 45%;
}
```

More customisation needed of course for every personal case, but I guess the code above is giving you the idea.[image]